# select statement should return count as zero if no row return using group by clause

Tags: oracle

I have a table student_info, it has column "status", status can be P (present), A (absent), S (ill), T ( transfer), L (left).

I am looking for  expected output as below.

```
status  count(*)
P       12
S       1
A       2
T       0
L       0
```

But output is coming like as below:

```
Status   Count(*)
P          12
S           1
A           2
```

we need rows against status T and L as well with count zero though no record exist in DB.

Comment: Do you have a table with all status values somewhere?

Comment: no , Its a field in same table student_info.

Comment: So how do you know you (only) need those five statuses?

Comment: those are only distinct status in that table.

Comment: @Roger - but they aren't all in the table - otherwise you'd see non-zero counts for them. Or are you filtering (perhaps on a date range) and those other statuses exist but only on rows that are filtered out? It would be helpful to include your current query and sample data in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store somewhere your statuses (pherhaps in another table). Otherwise, you list them using subquery:

```
with stored_statuses as (
  select 'P' code, 'present' description from dual
  union all 
  select 'A' code, 'absent' description from dual
  union all 
  select 'S' code, 'ill' description from dual
  union all 
  select 'T' code, 'transfer' description from dual
  union all 
  select 'L' code, 'left' description from dual
)
select ss.code, count(*) from student_info si
left join stored_statuses ss on ss.code = si.status
group by ss.code
```

Answer (score 2):

@mkuligowski's approach is close, but you need an outer join between the CTE providing all of the possible status values, and then you need to count the entries that actually match:

```
-- CTE to generate all possible status values
with stored_statuses (status) as (
            select 'A' from dual
  union all select 'L' from dual
  union all select 'P' from dual
  union all select 'S' from dual
  union all select 'T' from dual
)
select ss.status, count(si.status)
from stored_statuses ss
left join student_info si on si.status = ss.status
group by ss.status;

STATUS COUNT(SI.STATUS)
------ ----------------
P                    12
A                     2
T                     0
S                     1
L                     0
```

The CTE acts as a dummy table holding the five statuses you want to count. That is then outer joined to your real table - the outer join means the rows from the CTE are still included even if there is no match - and then the rows that *are* matched in your table are counted. That allows the zero counts to be included.

You could also do this with a collection:

```
select ss.status, count(si.status)
from (
  select column_value as status from table(sys.odcivarchar2list('A','L','P','S','T'))
) ss
left join student_info si on si.status = ss.status
group by ss.status;
```

It would be preferable to have a physical table which holds those values (and their descriptions); you could also then have a primary/foreign key relationship to enforce the allowed values in your existing table.

---

If all the status values actually appear in your table, but you have a filter which happens to exclude all rows for some of them, then you could get the list of all (used) values from the table itself instead of hard-coding it.

If your initial query was something like this, with a completely made-up filter:

```
select si.status, count(*)
from student_info si
where si.some_condition = 'true'
group by si.status;
```

then you could use a subquery to get all the distinct values from the unfiltered table, outer join from that to the same table, and apply the filter as part of the outer join condition:

```
select ss.status, count(si.status)
from (
  select distinct status from student_info
) ss
left join student_info si on si.status = ss.status
and si.some_condition = 'true'
group by ss.status;
```

It can't stay as a `where` clause (at least here, where it's applying to the right-hand-side of the outer join) because that would override the outer join and effectively turn it back into an inner join.

Comment: I would like to use where clause , where should it fit in this query.

Comment: @Roger - after the `left join` clause and before the `group by` clause. It might need to be an `and` for the outer join condition though, rather than a separate `where` clause though, to stop it falling back to being an inner join... So all the status values do actually exist in the table, they're just missed because they happen to be excluded by the `where` clause?